# Тип полей DATE and TIME в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Кто знает, поведайте, пожалуйста. Чем отличаются и что дают типы полей: DATE, TIME, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP и YEAR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Подробно обо всех типах данный mysql можно почитать тут: [типы данных MySQL](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/column-types.html). По поводу перечисленных вами типов:

> **DATE**
> Дата. Поддерживается интервал от '1000-01-01' до '9999-12-31'. MySQL выводит значения DATE в формате 'YYYY-MM-DD', но можно установить значения в столбец DATE, используя как строки, так и числа.
>
> **TIME**
> Время. Интервал от '-838:59:59' до '838:59:59'. MySQL выводит значения TIME в формате 'HH:MM:SS', но можно устанавливать значения в столбце TIME, используя как строки, так и числа.
>
> **DATETIME**
> Комбинация даты и времени. Поддерживается интервал от '1000-01-01 00:00:00' до '9999-12-31 23:59:59'. MySQL выводит значения DATETIME в формате 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', но можно устанавливать значения в столбце DATETIME, используя как строки, так и числа
>
> **TIMESTAMP**
> Временная метка. Интервал от '1970-01-01 00:00:00' до некоторого значения времени в 2037 году. MySQL выводит значения TIMESTAMP в форматах YYYYMMDDHHMMSS, YYMMDDHHMMSS, YYYYMMDD или YYMMDD в зависимости от значений M: 14 (или отсутствующее), 12, 8, или 6; но можно также устанавливать значения в столбце TIMESTAMP, используя как строки, так и числа. Столбец TIMESTAMP полезен для записи даты и времени при выполнении операций INSERT или UPDATE, так как при этом автоматически вносятся значения даты и времени самой последней операции, если эти величины не введены программой. Можно также устанавливать текущее значение даты и времени, задавая значение NULL
>
> **YEAR**
> Год в двухзначном или четырехзначном форматах (по умолчанию формат четырехзначный). Допустимы следующие значения: с 1901 по 2155, 0000 для четырехзначного формата года и 1970-2069 при использовании двухзначного формата (70-69). MySQL выводит значения YEAR в формате YYYY, но можно задавать значения в столбце YEAR, используя как строки, так и числа (тип данных YEAR недоступен в версиях, предшествующих MySQL 3.22)